# Problems with font

Tags: fonts

so im trying to use a local font that i upload to my server when i try to use the font it wont render properly but when i try the fonts on a local webserver ( no wp ) it works find and renders properly,

i have tried to use the web url to direct it to the link, using local dir, and using "use any fonts" but not of it works. i relised that it doesnt render properly because of "use any fonts" cause when i upload and view the font it renders like time new roman and the browser detects it as times new roman which is very confusing.

anyway here are the few thing that may help to solve this
Font : https://www.dafont.com/lintsec.font?text=font&back=theme
Font : https://www.dafont.com/army-rust.font?text=font ( i tried this once and it doesnt work to )
Use any font : https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-any-font/
the theme i use : https://wordpress.com/theme/apostrophe-2/wphusintest.wordpress.com
i tried using firefox and edge both says that the font is times new roman

i forgot to mention trying using cdn enabler but no luck and stop.

any way thanks in advance and help

Comment: Can you show us how you're including the font? It's normally a block of CSS that you'll have put in your theme or child theme, or in the customiser I'd expect. Or if you're having trouble with the CDN enabler, how did you try to set that up?

Comment: That said, this possibly isn't a WordPress-specific issue.

Comment: @font-face { font-family : 'fontname'; src : url(link); } i also tried using use any font, and i didnt use cdn enabler anymore. i think its wordpress because even when im using use any font it still dosnt show the correct font, and i just tried using google font but it still doesnt work, ive come to think that its the theme